# when trying to apply my code on data frame column i face the following list index out of range error

Tags: python, pandas

```py
data1 =pd.read_json('C:\\machine learning\\csvjson.json')
     data3=data1.iloc[4:]
     data3 = data3.reset_index()
     data3.drop('index',axis=1) 
    
        for i in range(len(data3['coverageData (S)'])):
                inpu_t = data3['coverageData (S)'].iloc[i]
                re_dict = (inpu_t[0])
                coverageStatsDict = (re_dict['CoverageStats'])
                blocksData = coverageStatsDict[0]
```

> IndexError: list index out of range at re_dict = (inpu_t[0])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexNe Posting a "how-to" link with no comment seems condescending to me. Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including input and expected output. As well, the full traceback might help.

Comment: Sorry, had this link on my clipboard and thought it was a good fit. Your code is not reproducible. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @AlexNe Thank you! *`[mcve]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to select particular columns. However, the way you used *iloc* selects rows, not columns ([Refer Pandas docs on iloc here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)).

If you are looking to select all rows and all columns 4th column on wards, this should do the trick. Try replacing

```
data3 = data1.iloc[4:]
```

with

```
data3 = data1.iloc[:, 4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

@sourvad
I was trying to select all rows from 4th row and columns from 0th column.
i have dataframe column whose values are list of dictionaries, from the above code what i was trying to do is get the list value of each row for the column and then get the 0th element of list whcih is a dictionary.
from the code i have written i can get the list values, but when trying to get the dictionary value which is "inpu_t[0]" i get the following above error